# NSUserDefaults save two arrays leading to crash

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

Recently I was studying `NSUserDefaults`, then made a demo as follows:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSMutableArray *activity_array = [NSMutableArray array];
 NSMutableArray *movie_array = [NSMutableArray array];
 [defaults setObject:activity_array forKey:@"activity"];
 [defaults setObject:movie_array forKey:@"movie"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

Then I tried writing the following which I will be calling "code2" for the duration of this post:

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSMutableArray *array = [userDefault objectForKey:@"activity"];
 [array addObject:@"123"];
```

the demo still works.
However the demo crashes when I replace "code2" with the following code:

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSMutableArray *array = [userDefault objectForKey:@"movie"];
 [array addObject:@"123"];
```

As you can see, the difference is the key.
Why does this crash?

Comment: Because your question is easy this wasn't asked of you, but please make sure to add crash logs/ stack trace when you say you have crashes. If you had done that you could've got the answer yourself, by reading the log, you can see that :  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object' ` is pretty clear means you're mutating an immutable object. ;-)

Comment: sir,i would like to ask more,as i ask the question because i would like to change the array stored by NSUserDefault.so what should i do?

Comment: If you want to modify the array's content and save it again, follow the instructions in my answer (the one you just accepted!). Step 1: Get the array from userdefaults, step2 : make a mutable copy of the array, step 3: add/remove the objects you want, step 4, save your array in the userdefaults, it's now modified !

Comment: I edited my answer to be a bit more clear

Comment: step 4,how to save?just [userDefaults synchronize]?i tryed,it failed.

Comment: You don't need to synchronize every time, look at the description when you alt+clic the "Synchronize" method, it explains when you have to do it.
To save in the NSUserDefaults, you do like you did before. `[NSUserDefaults setObject:youArray forKey:@"yourKey"]` and it's saved :)

Comment: could i use the same key?i tried in demo it also works,but in project it failed.because i would like to store some data use the array,and it constantly changes,so i need the key unchanged.

Comment: the need of my project with NSUserDefaults is constantly changed Value and unchanged key

Comment: Yes you can use the same key, it's like saving files. You can use the same file name, but if there is something there it will be overwritten. For example, if you save an array on key X, you will only find the array when you look at X. If you want to update your data you first have to get it, modify it, and then save it. If you want to delete something at key X, just save "nil" at the key :)

Comment: save = `setObjectForKey`, get = `objectForKey:`.   Imagine your putting data in boxes. but the boxes can only have one item. So if you put item A in  box 1, you can retrieve it later. If  you put item B in box 1, item A is overwritten. But you can take item A from box 1 and save it in box 3, or simply save an array of item A and B in box 1.

Comment: I think that if you're still struggling at this point you should read a tutorial and the apple  documentation, because I can't make myself clearer than this.

Comment: sir,i have solve the problem with your help,the following is my new question,hoping your help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366192/zxingobjc-integration-ios-but-didnt-work-at-all?noredirect=1#comment48824772_30366192

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` can store `NSMutableArrays`, but will turn them into immutable arrays.

Same  goes for `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary`.

That means if you want to add an object to an array that you just extracted from the `NSUserDefaults`, you will have to first make it mutable first, using `-mutableCopy` for example, or `-initWithArray`.

```
NSArray *array = [userDefault objectForKey:@"movie"];

//This works
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:array];

//This works too and is more commonly used.
NSMutableArray *arr = [array mutableCopy];
```

You can now modify the array `arr` without any trouble, and you will be able to save it just like you did before. If you retrieve it afterwards, it will be the modified array. But be careful, `arrays` and `dictionaries` are always immutable when taken from `NSUserDefaults`. You will have to do that "trick" everytime you want to modify an array or dictionary from the `NSUserDefaults`.

EDIT : after testing your code, my only assumption is that your crash-free array is simply nil when you retrieve it. Debug with breakpoints to verify this but I'm close to 101% sure.

EDIT2 : trojanfoe got that faster than I did !

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed-out the arrays you get back from `NSUserDefaults` are immutable, so an exception will be thrown when calling `addObject:` on them, however that won't occur if the array is `nil` as calling methods (sending messages) to objects that are `nil` are silently ignored.

Therefore I believe your code2 works as the object `@"activity"` doesn't exist in the user defaults, while `@"movie"` does.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and dictionaries returned from NSUserDefaults are always immutable, even if the one you set was mutable. You'll have to call -mutableCopy.

Comment: Have you double-checked that it's returning a non-nil object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *array = [[userDefault objectForKey:@"movie"]mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

The object from userDefault is not mutable.. Try this

```
NSMutableArray *arr = (NSMutableArray *)[userDefault objectForKey:@"activity"];
```

or if you like use id and check its class first to prevent crashing:

```
id variableName = [userDefault objectForKey:@"activity"];

if ([[variableName class] isEqual:[NSArray class]])
{
     NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)variableName];
     NSMutableArray *arr = [(NSArray *)variableName mutableCopy];
}
else if ([[variableName class] isEqual:[NSNull class]])
    NSLog(@"no object with key:activity");
else
    NSLog(@"not array");

//Happy coding.. :)
```